# select all many to many records alongside with parent table in one hit to database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a three table(Postgresql):

```
ModelA:
    model_a_id
    item1
    item2


ModelB:
    model_b_id
    item1
    item2


ModelA_ModelB:
    model_a_id foreign_key to ModelA
    model_b_id foreign_key to ModelB
```

Ok

I want to select All ModelA with all relation to ModelB.

what I want is:

```
[{
    Record1ModelA: {
        item1: 'A',
        item2: 'B',
        modelBList: [{
              Record1ModelB: {
                  item1: 'C',
                  item2: 'D'
              },
              Record2ModelB: {
                  item1: 'E',
                  item2: 'F'
              }
              ...
        }]
    },
    Record2ModelA: {
        item1: 'G',
        item2: 'H',
        modelBList: [{
              Record1ModelB: {
                  item1: 'I',
                  item2: 'G'
              },
              Record2ModelB: {
                  item1: 'K',
                  item2: 'L'
              }
              ...
        }]
    }
    ...
}]
```

**Question**:

1. Can I make this result with a hit to the database?
2. If yes, How can I achieve this result with SQL Query?

Comment: you can get all of the ibfo with a query, but not in the nested array as you described in the JSON, but in a "flat" array

Comment: @GuyL thanks. I did that in a `flat` array, Does ORM do the same in this way?

Comment: I don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Finally, I found an answer to this question:

Answer is: `json_agg` in postgresql

```
SELECT ModelA.model_a_id, ModelA.item1, ModelA.item2, json_agg(mb.*)
FROM ModelA
LEFT JOIN ModelA_ModelB as mab on ModelA.model_a_id = mab.model_a_id
LEFT JOIN  ModelB as mb on mb.model_b_id = mab.model_b_id
GROUP BY ModelA.model_a_id
```